# Need script to generate email with date/time stamp

Tags: javascript, email

I want to create a script, or even batch, that outputs an email address with the date/time the script is run as part of the email, and puts it in the clipboard or outputs it to be copied. For example, if I run it, an email address is generated like this support-08-30-22-09-19-00@servertest.com I use this for testing so that I can then search error logs with a more exact time, making it easier to narrow down the errors. Below is what I have for Powershell, but I'm wanting to know how to make it more user friendly, like execute it with just a double-click

```
$curDate = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss"
"support-" + $curDate + "@clickdimensions.com" | clip
```

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a free coding service. Please attempt to write the code yourself, and if you run into issues, ask a question that includes your code and what isn't working.

Comment: I've updated it, and thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should do the trick. You can obviously improve where necessary to fit your need.

```js
const generateEmail = () => {
    return document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    const dateTime = new Date();
    let month = (dateTime.getMonth()+1);
    let minutes = dateTime.getMinutes();
    let seconds = dateTime.getSeconds();

    if (month.toString().length < 2) {
        month = '0'+(dateTime.getMonth()+1);
    }
    if (minutes.toString().length < 2) {
        minutes = '0'+dateTime.getMinutes();
    }
    if (seconds.toString().length < 2) {
        seconds = '0'+dateTime.getMinutes();
    }
    const dateTimeNow = month+'-'+dateTime.getDate()+'-'+dateTime.getFullYear()+'-'+dateTime.getHours()+'-'+minutes+'-'+seconds;
    document.querySelector('p').innerText = 'support-'+dateTimeNow+'@domain.tld'
  });
}

generateEmail();
```

```html
<button>Generate Email</button>
<p></p>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Good answers provide some explanation of how the new code included within works

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
let email = "support-";
let date = new Date();

if ((date.getMonth()+1).toString().length < 2) {
  email += "0";
}
email += (date.getMonth()+1).toString();
email += "-";
if (date.getDate().toString().length < 2) {
  email += "0";
}
email += date.getDate().toString();
email += "-";
email += date.getFullYear().toString().slice(2);
email += "-";
if (date.getHours().toString().length < 2) {
  email += "0";
}
email += date.getHours().toString();
email += "-";
if (date.getMinutes().toString().length < 2) {
  email += "0";
}
email += date.getMinutes().toString();
email += "-";
if (date.getSeconds().toString().length < 2) {
  email += "0";
}
email += date.getSeconds().toString();
email += "@clickdimensions.com";
console.log(email);
```